# I get error messages when I connect my ESP8266 to my computer

Tags: esp8266

I'm a girl who loves coding and I'm 13 years old. I'm making a circuit for a competition and this is the first time I'm coding something. I am coding an ESP8266 for an air pollution monitoring system.

**Problem 1**
Though I've connected my ESP8266 to the laptop (via a micro USB cable that is totally alright), when I open Arduino IDE it does not detect the ESP8266. I've installed the correct drivers and installed everything needed in the Arduino IDE.

This is what I see:

[image]

**Problem 2**
I was trying to upload the blink code to my ESP8266 according to a tutorial on the internet, but it shows these error messages:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________
. Variables and constants in RAM (global, static), used 28456 / 80192 bytes (35%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ DATA     1496     initialized variables
╠══ RODATA   1208     constants       
╚══ BSS      25752    zeroed variables
. Instruction RAM (IRAM_ATTR, ICACHE_RAM_ATTR), used 60691 / 65536 bytes (92%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ ICACHE   32768    reserved space for flash instruction cache
╚══ IRAM     27923    code in IRAM    
. Code in flash (default, ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR), used 235060 / 1048576 bytes (22%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╚══ IROM     235060   code in flash   
Failed uploading: no upload port provided
__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

[image]

If there's anyone who can help me get through this I'd be really greatful about it. Thank you.

Comment: Is NODE MCU 1.0 the type of board that you have?

Comment: The second "error" is not an error - it just prints statistics and says the target can't be connected, because the first error is that the target was not found. You may have better luck asking on Arduino Stack Exchange, but my guess is that an ESP-12 is not an ESP8266 and you need to separately install a plug-in to add support for ESP8266 modules. Can this be migrated to Arduino.SE?

Comment: Have you told the Arduino IDE what serial port your board is connected to?

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/Quick-Start-Guide-to-Arduino-IDE-With-NodeMCU-ESP8/ Happy coding!

Comment: please add some more details on your hardware setup! You mention the ESP8266, but that's just a chip. ESP-12E is a module, but it doesn't have a micro-USB connector. So I'm assuming you have a module or breakout board; please describe how it is all wired together.

Comment: Personally, I have found the ESP8266 very difficult to work with. As Paul is suggesting, different companies sell different ESP8266-based modules that aren't totally compatible with each other, and instructions for one may totally fail for a different one. :-(

Answer (score 0):

you are good with the libraries i.e for esp8266 using esp 12E module so I don't think there is an issue there, I would suggest you to check your micro USB connector as all micro USB connects u find cant transfer data some have only the capability to charge.
how to check it, u can connect a keypad or any mobile phone with a micro USB pin using the same cable u r using for the project, if ur phone's storage details appear on the system in "removable disk" after accepting the notification if any appears on your phone for data transfer.
If the phone is getting charged but the storage data is not accessible on the system then the cable is only for charging and has no data transfer capabilities which make it to fail to connect ur esp8266 to Adriuno IDE

Comment: Please use proper wording and don't subsitute your with ur etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your driver then it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install this driver:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all#windows-710

Answer (score -1):

Change the board.
This can be because excessive usage of the board. this might have heated up the board and damaged it internally.

thy this out .

Comment: Hi! What is *excessive usage*, have the board been in use for more than x recommended amount of time, or has it been overloaded, overclocked? Also there's a lot of vague expressions *can be* *this might* and *thy this out* (the latter, try what?) that makes it all uncertain. Please edit your answer according to the guidelines at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/354158)